# command "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey" not found

Tags: vscode-tasks

I wrote tasks.json in vscode, but it doesn't work.  I think that vscode can not recognize "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey".

Here is the tasks I wrote.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "runner": "terminal",
    "type": "shell",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "save and compile for C/C++",
            "command": "${input:chooseCompiler}",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true,
                
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "chooseCompiler",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
          "args": {
            "*.cpp": "g++",
            "*.c": "gcc"
          }
        }
      ]
}
```

I expected the task to be selected automatically depending on the file extension, but it said "command "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey" not found". What should I do?

Comment: Where did you get `extension.commandvariable` from? It looks like you need to install some extension for it to work?

Comment: Have you installed the "Command Variable" extension?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. I installed "Command Variable" extension. Then change tasks.json "inputs" part.

```
"inputs": [
        {
          "id": "chooseCompiler",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
          "args": {
            ".cpp": "g++",
            ".c": "gcc"
          }
        }
      ]
```